# React Native WebView rendering blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

For a reason that I don't know, the webview component does not return a web page as I expect, instead it renders a blank white page. I tried it on web and Android physical device.
Moreover, I have googled a lot, but everything I tried does not work.

Here is the code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () => {
  return <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView source={{ uri: "https://google.com" }} />
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and reload app

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () => {
  return (     
     <WebView source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com/" }} />
  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to put your `WebView` tag inside `View` remove your `View` and `SafeAreaView` tag it will work fine
replace your code with this

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <WebView source={{ uri: "https://google.com" }} />
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Login
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem with this recently.

I was trying to display my pdf documents with WebView. But pdf documents were loading sometimes. Sometimes it just showed a blank page.

This is how I managed to solve this problem.

```
const WebViewExample = ({uri}) => {
    const webViewRef = useRef();

    // You can use uuid instead.
    // We have to change the key because sometimes it is not 
    // re-rendered in android platform after reload.
    const generateRandomKey = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 100000, 10);

    const [key, setKey] = useState(generateRandomKey());

    return (
        <WebView
            key={key}
            ref={webViewRef}
            syle={{flex: 1}}
            source={{uri: uri}}
            onLoadEnd={data => {
                const {nativeEvent} = data;
                const {title} = nativeEvent;

                if (!title.trim()) {
                    webViewRef.current?.stopLoading();
                    webViewRef.current?.reload();
                    setKey(generateRandomKey());
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

In the onLoadEnd return, we check the 'title' information of the page we have brought. If the 'title' data is empty, the page fetching failed. We reload the page and update the key value.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me remove `SafeAreaView`

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
const App = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <WebView source={{ uri: url }} />
        </View>
    )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SafeAreaView` then give it flex 1 ..

```html
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';


const App = () => {
    return <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
                source={{ uri: "https://google.com" }} />
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

export default App
```